# Closed Source Android Library Distribution

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I'm writing a closed source android library that I would like to distribute. On my local development environment I have setup maven and I am uploading my generated aar to that local maven repository. I then add the local repository in my gradle build files and specify my library as a dependency. This all works without any problems.

I would like to do the same setup with a maven repo hosted on a remote server. My guess is I need to secure this remote maven repo with a username and password and specify these credentials in my gradle build files along with the path of the maven repo. I can't find out how to do that though, any pointers?

Also, my understanding is maven central and sonatype are for open source libraries. Are there any solutions for closed source libraries distribution that is like maven central?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up installing Archiva on an EC2 instance and using it to host the maven repos.